# Size of video container in receiver

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I know this is ridiculous, but I'm learning...

In a Chrome application I let my sender initiate and load a Custom receiver.
The receiver page includes a **video** element set to play one specific video, like this:

```
<video autoplay>
    <source src="../media/someVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The receiver page and the media file are hosted on a web server (SP)

I use no further communication between sender and receiver, so the receiver just loads and plays the video.
It works beautifully, but the video size on the device (TV) is too big. It fills the screen, but I don't see the full picture.

I try to downsize the video using CSS or by setting the width and height parameters on the **video** element, but the result is the same. Why doesn't ChromeCast respect these settings?

Answer (score 0):

width/height for the video element should work. As a test, just set width and height in the element itself and test. On a tv screen, in general, there is a notion of [overscan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan) and most modern tv sets have a setting to adjust that, you might want to check to see if your tv offers that too or not.

Comment: Thanks Ali, you're right.
    <video autoplay width="960" height="540">
does work. I just didn't go down enough in size to notice the difference. 
The CSS version (element, id or class selectors) doesn't work.